# How to scale column numbers in a pgfplot table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want the numbers in my second column in `dataTest.dat` file be multiplied by 1E4, and it seems that `\addplot table[x=x,y=10000*y] {dataTest.dat};` does not work, what should I do then? Here is the code,

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex 
\documentclass[class=article,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[x=x,y=y] {dataTest.dat}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the `dataTest.dat` file:

```
x y
 1 0.00004
 2 0.00460
 3 0.00114
 4 0.00037
 5 0.00017
 6 0.00010
 7 0.00010
 8 0.00010
 9 0.00010
10 0.00010
11 0.00010
12 0.00010
13 0.00010
14 0.00010
```

Comment: It's `y expr=\thisrow{y}*1000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible solution. Use `filter` code which gets input coordinates as #1, applies some operations and writes result into the macro `pgfmathresult`.

```
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*10000}\pgfmathresult}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[class=article,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{filecontents*}{dataTest.dat}
x y
 1 0.00004
 2 0.00460
 3 0.00114
 4 0.00037
 5 0.00017
 6 0.00010
 7 0.00010
 8 0.00010
 9 0.00010
10 0.00010
11 0.00010
12 0.00010
13 0.00010
14 0.00010
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1*10000}\pgfmathresult}]
\addplot table[x=x,y=y] {dataTest.dat}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```